# Leer url de un archivo local en formato json en laravel desde js

Tags: javascript, laravel, json, rutas

Estoy intentando importar un archivo json que está en el proyecto realizado en laravel que es para traducir la tabla del plugin Data table, pero no lo consigo.

Esto es lo que tengo y el directorio donde esta el archivo:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El codigo que tengo en la vista:

```
 <script>
            $(document).ready(function() {

                $('.employees_table').DataTable({
                    processing: true,
                    serverSide: true,
                    responsive: true,
                    ajax: "{{ route('cuentas.listar') }}",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: "POST",
                    language: {
                        // "url": "//cdn.datatables.net/plug-ins/1.10.15/i18n/Spanish.json"
                       // "url": "{{URL::to('/')}}/assets/lang/es/datatable.json" 
                       "url": "{{ resource_path('/lang/es/datatable.json')}}" 
                    },
                    dom: 'Bfrtip',
                    buttons: [
                        'copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf', 'print'
                    ],
                    columns: [{
                            data: 'id',
                            name: 'id'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'nombre',
                            name: 'nombre',
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'descripcion',
                            name: 'descripcion'
                        },
                        {
                            data: 'actions',
                            name: 'actions',
                            searchable: false,
                            orderable: false
                        }
                    ],

                })
            })
        </script>
```

Este es el archivo datatable.json:

```
{
    "processing": "Procesando...",
    "lengthMenu": "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
    "zeroRecords": "No se encontraron resultados",
    "emptyTable": "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
    "infoEmpty": "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0 registros",
    "infoFiltered": "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
    "search": "Buscar:",
    "infoThousands": ",",
    "loadingRecords": "Cargando...",
    "paginate": {
        "first": "Primero",
        "last": "Último",
        "next": "Siguiente",
        "previous": "Anterior"
    },
    "aria": {
        "sortAscending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
        "sortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
    },
    "buttons": {
        "copy": "Copiar",
        "colvis": "Visibilidad",
        "collection": "Colección",
        "colvisRestore": "Restaurar visibilidad",
        "copyKeys": "Presione ctrl o u2318 + C para copiar los datos de la tabla al portapapeles del sistema. <br \/> <br \/> Para cancelar, haga clic en este mensaje o presione escape.",
        "copySuccess": {
            "1": "Copiada 1 fila al portapapeles",
            "_": "Copiadas %d fila al portapapeles"
        },
        "copyTitle": "Copiar al portapapeles",
        "csv": "CSV",
        "excel": "Excel",
        "pageLength": {
            "-1": "Mostrar todas las filas",
            "_": "Mostrar %d filas"
        },
        "pdf": "PDF",
        "print": "Imprimir"
    },
    "autoFill": {
        "cancel": "Cancelar",
        "fill": "Rellene todas las celdas con <i>%d<\/i>",
        "fillHorizontal": "Rellenar celdas horizontalmente",
        "fillVertical": "Rellenar celdas verticalmentemente"
    },
    "decimal": ",",
    "searchBuilder": {
        "add": "Añadir condición",
        "button": {
            "0": "Constructor de búsqueda",
            "_": "Constructor de búsqueda (%d)"
        },
        "clearAll": "Borrar todo",
        "condition": "Condición",
        "conditions": {
            "date": {
                "after": "Despues",
                "before": "Antes",
                "between": "Entre",
                "empty": "Vacío",
                "equals": "Igual a",
                "notBetween": "No entre",
                "notEmpty": "No Vacio",
                "not": "Diferente de"
            },
            "number": {
                "between": "Entre",
                "empty": "Vacio",
                "equals": "Igual a",
                "gt": "Mayor a",
                "gte": "Mayor o igual a",
                "lt": "Menor que",
                "lte": "Menor o igual que",
                "notBetween": "No entre",
                "notEmpty": "No vacío",
                "not": "Diferente de"
            },
            "string": {
                "contains": "Contiene",
                "empty": "Vacío",
                "endsWith": "Termina en",
                "equals": "Igual a",
                "notEmpty": "No Vacio",
                "startsWith": "Empieza con",
                "not": "Diferente de"
            },
            "array": {
                "not": "Diferente de",
                "equals": "Igual",
                "empty": "Vacío",
                "contains": "Contiene",
                "notEmpty": "No Vacío",
                "without": "Sin"
            }
        },
        "data": "Data",
        "deleteTitle": "Eliminar regla de filtrado",
        "leftTitle": "Criterios anulados",
        "logicAnd": "Y",
        "logicOr": "O",
        "rightTitle": "Criterios de sangría",
        "title": {
            "0": "Constructor de búsqueda",
            "_": "Constructor de búsqueda (%d)"
        },
        "value": "Valor"
    },
    "searchPanes": {
        "clearMessage": "Borrar todo",
        "collapse": {
            "0": "Paneles de búsqueda",
            "_": "Paneles de búsqueda (%d)"
        },
        "count": "{total}",
        "countFiltered": "{shown} ({total})",
        "emptyPanes": "Sin paneles de búsqueda",
        "loadMessage": "Cargando paneles de búsqueda",
        "title": "Filtros Activos - %d"
    },
    "select": {
        "cells": {
            "1": "1 celda seleccionada",
            "_": "%d celdas seleccionadas"
        },
        "columns": {
            "1": "1 columna seleccionada",
            "_": "%d columnas seleccionadas"
        },
        "rows": {
            "1": "1 fila seleccionada",
            "_": "%d filas seleccionadas"
        }
    },
    "thousands": ".",
    "datetime": {
        "previous": "Anterior",
        "next": "Proximo",
        "hours": "Horas",
        "minutes": "Minutos",
        "seconds": "Segundos",
        "unknown": "-",
        "amPm": [
            "AM",
            "PM"
        ],
        "months": {
            "0": "Enero",
            "1": "Febrero",
            "10": "Noviembre",
            "11": "Diciembre",
            "2": "Marzo",
            "3": "Abril",
            "4": "Mayo",
            "5": "Junio",
            "6": "Julio",
            "7": "Agosto",
            "8": "Septiembre",
            "9": "Octubre"
        },
        "weekdays": [
            "Dom",
            "Lun",
            "Mar",
            "Mie",
            "Jue",
            "Vie",
            "Sab"
        ]
    },
    "editor": {
        "close": "Cerrar",
        "create": {
            "button": "Nuevo",
            "title": "Crear Nuevo Registro",
            "submit": "Crear"
        },
        "edit": {
            "button": "Editar",
            "title": "Editar Registro",
            "submit": "Actualizar"
        },
        "remove": {
            "button": "Eliminar",
            "title": "Eliminar Registro",
            "submit": "Eliminar",
            "confirm": {
                "_": "¿Está seguro que desea eliminar %d filas?",
                "1": "¿Está seguro que desea eliminar 1 fila?"
            }
        },
        "error": {
            "system": "Ha ocurrido un error en el sistema (<a target=\"\\\" rel=\"\\ nofollow\" href=\"\\\">Más información&lt;\\\/a&gt;).<\/a>"
        },
        "multi": {
            "title": "Múltiples Valores",
            "info": "Los elementos seleccionados contienen diferentes valores para este registro. Para editar y establecer todos los elementos de este registro con el mismo valor, hacer click o tap aquí, de lo contrario conservarán sus valores individuales.",
            "restore": "Deshacer Cambios",
            "noMulti": "Este registro puede ser editado individualmente, pero no como parte de un grupo."
        }
    },
    "info": "Mostrando _START_ a _END_ de _TOTAL_ registros"
}
```

El error es que no encuentra la ruta y ma aparece asi:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Como comento el compañero, el helper q estoy utilizando no sirve ya que es un path.

La solución fue mover el archivo en carpeta public y utilizar el helper **asset**

```
 "url": "{{ asset('datatable.json')}}"
```

Answer (score 3):

Este tipo de errores se presentan cuando tratas de cargar archivos directamente de tu servidor a un recurso que hace un llamado a un servicio de tu servidor, en otras palabras, un endpoint o url.

En este orden, si usas el helper [resource_path](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/helpers#method-resource-path), la documentación muy claramente te dice que recibirás un *fully qualified path*, que no es más que una ruta de este estilo:

- **/var/www/html/path/project** o en Windows: **C://path/project**

Lo que hace inentendible el recurso para la opciones de tu datatable. Tu datatable acepta un json, es verdad. [Puede recibir una url](https://datatables.net/reference/option/language.url), es verdad, pero es eso, una **URL**. Lo que le envías con *resource_path* no es una url, para eso debes hacer uso de un servidor para que te entregue una url del tipo: http://your.domain.com/assets/lang/file.json

En ese momento podrás acceder a las opciones del lenguaje y usar lo que necesitas.

Saludos